# Restrict `fill` to last occurrence of pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have data such as this:

```
df <- structure(list(line = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", 
                              "007", "008", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", "014"), 
                     utterance = c("((m: both hands", 
                                   "((m: both hands", 
                                   "((i: DH=1, SZ=0", "((i: DH=1, SZ=0", 
                                   "((s: Preface))", "((m: both hands", 
                                   "((m: both hands clasped", 
                                   "((m: both hands clasped", 
                                   "((s: Background))", "((m: enumerating", 
                                   "((m: enumerating", 
                                   "((s: End))", "((i: DH=1, SZ=0", "((m: relax gesture))"
                              )), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a new column `story` and `fill` that column with those values from column `utterance` that match the regex pattern `\\(\\(s`. But I want the `fill` to **stop at the last value matching such pattern**, which is `((s: End))`.

This `fill` command does **not** stop at that pattern - how can I stop `fill` at the pattern?

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(story = ifelse(grepl("\\(\\(s", utterance), utterance, NA)) %>%
  fill(story, .direction = "down")
   line               utterance             story
1   001         ((m: both hands              <NA>
2   002         ((m: both hands              <NA>
3   003         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
4   004         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
5   005          ((s: Preface))    ((s: Preface))
6   006         ((m: both hands    ((s: Preface))
7   007 ((m: both hands clasped    ((s: Preface))
8   008 ((m: both hands clasped    ((s: Preface))
9   009       ((s: Background)) ((s: Background))
10  010        ((m: enumerating ((s: Background))
11  011        ((m: enumerating ((s: Background))
12  012              ((s: End))        ((s: End))
13  013         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0        ((s: End))
14  014    ((m: relax gesture))        ((s: End))
```

**Desired**:

```
   line               utterance             story
1   001         ((m: both hands              <NA>
2   002         ((m: both hands              <NA>
3   003         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
4   004         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
5   005          ((s: Preface))    ((s: Preface))
6   006         ((m: both hands    ((s: Preface))
7   007 ((m: both hands clasped    ((s: Preface))
8   008 ((m: both hands clasped    ((s: Preface))
9   009       ((s: Background)) ((s: Background))
10  010        ((m: enumerating ((s: Background))
11  011        ((m: enumerating ((s: Background))
12  012              ((s: End))        ((s: End))
13  013         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
14  014    ((m: relax gesture))              <NA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr::fill` itself doesn't do that, but you can add one more `mutate`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(story = if_else(grepl("\\(\\(s", utterance), utterance, NA_character_)) %>%
  fill(story, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(story = if_else(story == last(story) & duplicated(story), NA_character_, story))
#    line               utterance             story
# 1   001         ((m: both hands              <NA>
# 2   002         ((m: both hands              <NA>
# 3   003         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
# 4   004         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
# 5   005          ((s: Preface))    ((s: Preface))
# 6   006         ((m: both hands    ((s: Preface))
# 7   007 ((m: both hands clasped    ((s: Preface))
# 8   008 ((m: both hands clasped    ((s: Preface))
# 9   009       ((s: Background)) ((s: Background))
# 10  010        ((m: enumerating ((s: Background))
# 11  011        ((m: enumerating ((s: Background))
# 12  012              ((s: End))        ((s: End))
# 13  013         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
# 14  014    ((m: relax gesture))              <NA>
```

This looks for the last occurrence of `story` and removes all but the first of that. This assumes that order matters, and does *not* assume that the last `story` must include the literal `s: End`, though you can update the logic accordingly if you prefer.

FYI, I changed from `ifelse` to `if_else`, as it is type-safe (`base::ifelse` is not). It requires being specific about *which* `NA` to use (there are over six different variants).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.locf`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
  mutate(story = ifelse(grepl("\\(\\(s", utterance), utterance, NA), 
    ind = match("((s: End))", story),
   story = replace(story, seq_len(first(ind)), 
    zoo::na.locf0(story[seq_len(first(ind))])), ind = NULL)
```

-output

```
 line               utterance             story
1   001         ((m: both hands              <NA>
2   002         ((m: both hands              <NA>
3   003         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
4   004         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
5   005          ((s: Preface))    ((s: Preface))
6   006         ((m: both hands    ((s: Preface))
7   007 ((m: both hands clasped    ((s: Preface))
8   008 ((m: both hands clasped    ((s: Preface))
9   009       ((s: Background)) ((s: Background))
10  010        ((m: enumerating ((s: Background))
11  011        ((m: enumerating ((s: Background))
12  012              ((s: End))        ((s: End))
13  013         ((i: DH=1, SZ=0              <NA>
14  014    ((m: relax gesture))              <NA>
```